# Object of type 'int' has no len

Tags: python

I'm new here, but I thought someone might be able to help me with something I have been working on for a little while now.

So I have been working on re-vamping fishing on a Toontown Fellowship source code, but after some time, I wound up with an error. The code is provided along with a picture of the Traceback.

```
for genus, speciesList in __fishDict.items():
    for species in range(len(speciesList)):
        __totalNumFish += 1
        speciesDesc = speciesList[species]
        rarity = speciesDesc[RARITY_INDEX]
        zoneList = speciesDesc[ZONE_LIST_INDEX]
        for zoneIndex in range(len(zoneList)):
            zone = zoneList[zoneIndex]
            effectiveRarity = getEffectiveRarity(rarity, zoneIndex)
            if zone == Anywhere:
                for rodIndex, rarityDict in __anywhereDict.items():
                    if canBeCaughtByRod(genus, species, rodIndex):
                        fishList = rarityDict.setdefault(effectiveRarity, [])
                        fishList.append((genus, species))
```

And the Traceback occurs on line 785. [Object of type int has no len](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVjpV.png)

Any help with correcting this would be greatly appreciated! (Oh yeah, and this occurred when I tried to add a new genus to the fish list.)

Comment: Line 785 doesn't mean much to us.

Comment: Hint add `print(type(zoneList), repr(zoneList))` right before the `for` loop.

Comment: Since `speciesList` and `zoneList` have `List` in their names I think those should be lists which they are not, obviously. Assuming this I think using `len()` is correct, but you should check where those variables came from since those are `int`s and not `list`s.

Comment: @albert The 'speciesList' part is where all of the species are defined based on a minimum weight, maximum weight, rarity, and where they are found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `len(zoneList)` when `zoneList` is an `int` in python. 
 Instead use `len(str(zoneList))` if you want the number of digits.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the Traceback error at line 785. Now there's a NEW error on the very next line: tuple index out of range, but I will see if I can't figure out how to fix that myself.

Comment: As I said in my comment above you should take some considerations about _the reason_ for the error. Was there just a mistake in your code or did you pass wrong datatypes? If the second case is true, you should check _where_ you got the data from...

Comment: Ah, I see. The speciesList is created from the tuple above it called __fishDict, which in turn creates another thing called speciesDesc. The zoneList is created from speciesDesc using ZONE_LIST_INDEX (which comes from ToontownGlobals)